# How to using Mesh for making transaction from specific address of seed and send ADA to another address

Tags: transaction, blockfrost, mesh

I was trying to make 1000 ADA addresses from one seed. I have used MESH and make payment addresses.
and deposit successfully on those addresses, now I need to send ADA from one of these generated addresses to another address using mesh and Blockfrost.

```
import { BlockfrostProvider } from '@meshsdk/core';
import { Transaction, ForgeScript, AppWallet } from '@meshsdk/core';
//ADA address generation
const blockchainProvider = new BlockfrostProvider('mainneteerretu');

const wallet = new AppWallet({
networkId: 1,
fetcher: blockchainProvider,
submitter: blockchainProvider,
key: {
type: 'mnemonic',
words: [
   "topic", "topic", "topic", "topic", "topic", "topic", "topic", "topic", 
   "topic", "topic", "topic", "topic", "topic", "topic", "topic", "topic", 
  "topic", "topic", "topic", "topic", 
  ],
 },
});

const address1 = wallet.getPaymentAddress(854);
const address2 = wallet.getPaymentAddress(855);


const utxos = await blockchainProvider.fetchAddressUTxOs(address1);



const forgingScript = ForgeScript.withOneSignature(address1);

const tx = new Transaction({ initiator: wallet });
tx.setRequiredSigners([address1]).sendLovelace(
  address2,
  "1000000"
);

const unsignedTx = await tx.build();

const signedTx = await wallet.signTx(unsignedTx);

const txHash = await wallet.submitTx(signedTx);
```

please note me where must change.

Comment: At a first glance, the code looks ok. Can you please share more details on the problem? How do you start the code? Do you get an error message?